# Fast Gaussian Filtering Using a Permutohedral Lattice

Tags: graphical-model, filter, conditional-random-field

I'm trying to implement
http://www.dabi.temple.edu/~zoran/papers/KostaAAAI13.pdf
but am stack at understanding equations 10) and 11).
They claim that the sum of the Gauss kernel multiplied with the mean is equivalent to convolving the mean with a Gauss kernel.

So far so good, next they say this could be approximated by filtering using the permutohedral lattice which I guess means using the features as the grid to filter the mean. This, given my understanding is correct, is also fine.

However the last claim (basically building on equation 11)) is that one could use the lattice to calculate the sum of the gaussian kernel. This is a bit more difficult for me to understand and I fail to see how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

After some further discussions, I've realised that the sum of the kernel could be calculated analogous to normal convolution. I.e. by convolving (or filtering) with a matrix of 1s.